# VS Code Remote Tunnels Slow Not Loading All Assets

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

Here is an overview of the setup I'm trying to achieve and the issue.

***Setup***

I have a **Local Network**

**Host** computer has WSL installed with my development environment in it.

I setup **"Remote Tunnel Access"** on the Host Computer via the VS Code GUI and GitHub.

I got to my **Client** computer and connect to the tunnel and then into the WSL instance. All works fine. I can access the remote WSL terminal, do all my work, etc.

***Issue***

When I boot my local development server, I can access it via localhost:3000 on the client computer as you would expect; however, many of the assets from the dev server timeout. It's as if there is some bandwidth limit.

If I go back to the host machine and boot localhost:3000 everything works fine. But on the client over the tunnel assets stop loading after reaching maybe 500kb of downloads. I've tried Nuxt, Next and pure HTML servers, and they all start timing out on assets over the remote tunnel.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same issue. My vscode's tunnels suddenly became very slow for no reason. When I setup a tunnel by myself with SSH, it works like a charm.

Comment: This seems to perform better when using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost, but still not as fast as over SSH. So maybe some sorta DNS issue I haven't been able to resolve yet.